# Primary key selectSelect from checklist

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

I'm workin on app, it has multiple checklist, from which user can select the items, the items are generated from SQLite.
I've used the following but it just give me string of the selected one.

This is my Product.java

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


          ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES +
                        " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pro_name text);");
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES +
                        " Values ('1','Milk');");
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES +
                        " Values ('2','Sugar');");
                sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                        SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES +
                        " Values ('3','Oil');");
            }
            finally{
                if (sampleDB != null) 
                    sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAMES);
                    sampleDB.close();
            }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, new ArrayList()));

        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }

    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (String item : items) {
                publishProgress(item);
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
            }

            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            ((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            setSelection(3);
            Toast.makeText(Product.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) v;
        check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
         String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(check.isChecked())
        {
            Toast.makeText(Product.this, "Item are Checked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!check.isChecked()&&!check.isChecked())
        {
            Toast.makeText(Product.this, "Item are not checked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
        vi=inf.inflate(R.layout.total, null);
        vi.setTag(cursor.getInt(0));
        return vi;
    }
```

Here is Final.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.total);
        txtEmps=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmps);
        txtPro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPro);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        startPKCounter();
        }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{

            dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
                        txtEmps.setText(txtEmps.getText()+String.valueOf(dbHelper.getEmployeeCount()));
            }
        finally
            {
            }
        super.onStart();
    }
    private void startPKCounter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Counted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        int primaryValue= (int)v.getTag(cursor);
        Toast.makeText(Final.this, primaryValue+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```

It is giving me error on v.getTag ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

See the `long id` part there?  That (`id`) is the primary key of the list item you clicked on.

Comment: alright..but how to view all that on next Tab..the list consist of 10 items, and on next Tab, the checked item should be displayed along with their Primary keys.. it is just giving me Toast message of the checked item...